# How can you modify the odds of winning at a wheel spin?

Tags: probability

So lets say you have a wheel divided in x sector
[image]

You want to rig the wheel to decrease the chances of someone landing on the green circle.
Now lets say you do it by putting magnets in the red object between each sector.
The magnets each have a value ranging between 0 (no attraction) and 1 (normal attraction) and depending on their force they slow the wheel a little everytime one passes the blue metal bar.

For a number x of sector and given the force of the spin and the initial rotation of the wheel are random, is there a way to set the values of the magnets so that your odds of winning are lower ?

Comment: This sounds like more of a physics question. You might try at [physics.se](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The use of the magnets or the wheel is just to explain the problem with an exemple, but the magnets are actually juste a value

Comment: I see. So you model the magnets as just decreasing the spinner by a fixed velocity at each passing, instead of applying a constant force at all times. It still might be on-topic for physics but I will +1 because it is interesting.

Comment: You can say "the magnets are actually just a value", but you haven't defined what effect that value has, and that information is absolutely necessary to answer this question. It seems obvious to me that you want maximum impedence for crossing all boundaries except on the exit side of the green sector, where it should be minimized. But what would be "maximum" and "minimum impedence" is going to depend on how one interprets these values.

Comment: The value of the magnet just represent how much it slows the wheel down, but I believe that the question can be answered generally without having to precise by how much they slow it down. I just want to know how the values of the magnets should be distributed around the wheel